# Writing to Label.Content from code behinde using Symbola Font

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

need to write musical symbols to my C# WPF application. Found Symbola font, that contains them and can write the symbols in XAML. But I need to add them frome code behinde.
- For importing font to my app I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912794/10985932
- In XAML I can write symbols to TextBlock or Label by this:

`<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="&#x1d11a;" FontFamily="{StaticResource Symbola}" FontSize="50.0" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Regular"/>
<Label x:Name="lab" Content="&#x1d11a;" FontFamily="{StaticResource Symbola}" FontSize="50"></Label>`

But don't know how to change Text or Content from code behinde. Tried to search, hoping using `Application.Current.Resources["Symbola"]` could help, but dont know how to access concrete "char" in this font.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the controls by name in the code behind and then set the Text property for the Textblock and the Content property for the Label

```
myTextBlock.Text = "\U0001D11A";
lab.Content = "\U0001D111";
```

Comment: Problem is, that symbols I need to display have more than 16bits code :-/

Comment: I've updated my answer to to use an eight digit `\U` literal. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934250/unicode-character-u1fxyz-not-outputting-correctly-when-used-in-code-behind

Comment: Thank you very much, Wes :-) Don't know how I could miss so many good answers for my question. Now I see many of them, just ask wrong before

Answer (score 0):

Tried some other idea and found solution here [How to convert emoticons to its UTF-32/escaped unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728740/how-to-convert-emoticons-to-its-utf-32-escaped-unicode) in ckuris comment. Used `Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1d11a)`and that's what I needed